# How to link time series to data range rather than dashboard time control

Tags: grafana

I have a time series chart that I'm querying from postgres.  I want the time range shown on the chart to be decided by the data returned, not the time series control for the dashboard.  Is that possible?  I know you can set relative time and time shift query options but they seem to just offset the range, not define a custom range.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately not a detailed answer, but more like a comment (which I cannot yet make), but what you are looking for is not possible in Grafana.

The built-in interval variables are on the level of the dashboard, and you cannot overwrite these on the level of a panel. The situation is maybe more apparent if you think of this interval variable of the dashboard as any other custom variable that you define. You can interact with them on the dashboard level but only read them on the panel level.